# Modify control name based on Counter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List<> of object, and for each object, I create a line in a table:

```
@for(int cnt=0; cnt< Model.Transaction.TransactionLines.Count; cnt++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="@("cmbCategory" + cnt.ToString())" class="col-lg-1 control-label">Category:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Transaction.TransactionLines[cnt].CategoryId,
                                  new SelectList(Model.TransactionReferences.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.Transaction.TransactionLines[cnt].CategoryId), "Select one",
                                  new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(0)", @class = "cmbCategory0 form-control" })
    </div>
```

...

As you can see, though, in the code, I have hard coded the "0" in the markup. I need that to reflect the value if the Cntr variable in the "for" loop.

i.e. `@onchange = "populateSubCategory(0)"`

How can I replace the 0, with @cntr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use string concatenation:

```
new { @onchange = "populateSubCategory(" + cnt + ")", @class = "cmbCategory0 form-control" })
```

Or use `string.Format()`:

```
new { @onchange = string.Format("populateSubCategory({0})", cnt), @class = "cmbCategory0 form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an MVC guy, but why can't you just concatenate the string,

e.g.

new { "onchange =\"populateSubCategory(", cnt.ToString(), "\", class=\"cmbCategory", cnt.ToString(), " form-control\"" })